# Interactive map link not clickable within description

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I have found this piece of code which is very suitable for my site, I am going to use it as our site map, however the link I have embedded within the div is not clickable, any ideas?

Thanks a lot

HTML

```
<div class="distribution-map">
<img src="image.jpg">

<button class="map-point" style="top:16%;left:45%">
<div class="content">
<div class="centered-y">
<h2>Top Menu</h2>
<p><a href="http://www.google.com/">This is a link</a> for Google</p>
</div>
</div>
</button>
</div>
```

CSS

```
h2 {
color: white;
}

div, img, footer {
position: relative;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.description {
max-width: 600px;
margin: 0 auto;
color: rgba(229, 229, 229, 0.7);
}

.centered {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.centered-y {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
top: 50%;
-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.distribution-map {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
padding: 20px;
box-sizing: border-box;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.distribution-map > img {
width: 100%;
position: relative;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.distribution-map .map-point {
cursor: pointer;
outline: none;
z-index: 0;
position: absolute;
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
border-radius: 20px;
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80);
opacity: 0.8;
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-moz-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, width 0.25s ease-in-out  0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, z-index 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s;
-o-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, width 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, z-index 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s;
-webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out, width 0.25s ease-in-out, height 0.25s ease-in-out, z-index 0.25s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition-delay: 0.25s, 0.25s, 0.25s, 0.25s;
-webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, width 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, z-index 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s;
transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, width 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, z-index 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s;
background: rgba(26, 26, 26, 0.85);
border: 5px solid #7fcff7;
}
.distribution-map .map-point .content {
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
left: 50%;
-webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
transform: translateX(-50%);
overflow: overlay;
}
.distribution-map .map-point:active, .distribution-map .map-point:focus {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(enabled=false);
opacity: 1;
width: 300px;
height: 220px;
color: #e5e5e5;
z-index: 1;
-webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out, width 0.25s ease-in-out,     height 0.25s ease-in-out; 
transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out, width 0.25s ease-in-out, height 0.25s ease-in-out;
}
.distribution-map .map-point:active .content, .distribution-map .map-point:focus .content {
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(enabled=false);
opacity: 1;
-moz-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out, overflow 0.25s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out, overflow 0.25s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out, height 0.25s ease-in-out, overflow 0.25s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition-delay: 0.25s, 0s, 0s;
-webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out, overflow 0.25s ease-in-out;
transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out, overflow 0.25s ease-in-out;
overflow: hidden;
}
.distribution-map .map-point:active .content a:hover, .distribution-map .map-point:active .content a:active, .distribution-map .map-point:focus .content a:hover, .distribution-map .map-point:focus .content   a:active {
 color: #afe1fa;
```

}

Comment: did you copy this wholesale from somewhere else? `<div>` within a `<button>` element is not valid html.

Comment: and only tag `<a>` can be clickable, button hasn't any events

Comment: It would be great to see the code on jsfiddle.net. But if you want to make a button act like link you need to wrap it inside a tag

Comment: @dsb yes  `for Google` is not in `a` tag